# Heroku shows no Vue.js changes with laravel

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js, heroku, production

well I have a problem with heroku (PasS), I am launching my first project with Laravel and I'm currently making constant changes,
I understand that every change I make in development I have to use git and push heroku to send to production and also to see the changes in vue.js I have to execute a command in heroku bash, now my problem is because the changes I currently make it no longer works it is not seen in production, constantly made many commits it will be for that or for the cache I do not know the truth I hope a response please.

[image]

Comment: What does "and also to see the changes in vue.js I have to execute a command in heroku bash" mean? What command are you running? This likely isn't correct.

Comment: ah Srry execute on heroku bash => npm run dev Executed that command see the changes in the front-end

Comment: [That whole image should be shared as _text_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). Images can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: It looks like that builds a bunch of artifacts on your local filesystem. As I suspected, this should _not_ be done on Heroku. Its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) means that anything you build that way will be lost the next time your dyno restarts. You need to build artifacts _during the build phase_ of your deployment, so they're captured in your application slug.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I do not understand you well or maybe it is because of my lack of ignorance since it is my first project that I launch to heroku, However I will detail my problem currently I have two branches: master and production, currently I always work with the master branch and also that's where I push the changes to heroku
Here I show you a message from the list of my commits in the master branch:
[image]

in conclusion :
I have created a component in vue.js and when I deployed the application to heroku, that component is not shown and as I said in heroku bash it executed "npm run dev" to show the changes in the front-end, previously it showed the changes it made but over time I stop working
And as I say I think it is for making many commits